# How to find the path for the most negatively-weighted cycle which goes through a specific source node?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

I am trying to find the path for the most negative cycle in a graph G which starts and ends at a specified source node S.

I have studied an application/ extension of the Bellman-Ford algorithm (henceforth referred to as the "Huang algorithm") found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.1981&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which describes how to find a negative cycle reachable from a specified node. However, this does not ensure that the "full cycle" going from S -> cycle -> S is negative.

Here is my current research into this topic:

On the n<sup>th</sup> iteration of the Bellman Ford algorithm, if an edge can be relaxed, then the graph contains a negative cycle. Using the Huang algorithm I can retrace the path of the negative cycle through the predecessor dictionary until a vertex repeats. When a vertex repeats, I cease iterating over the predecessor and now have my path for the negative cycle. However, the source vertex is often not in this path. I believe it is also sometimes not the most negatively-weighted path.

I would like to find the most negative cycle of which S is a part. (This can include a cycle with a subcycle detected by the Huang algorithm)

Comment: Are you looking for a *simple* cycle?  (i.e., no vertex is repeated)  Otherwise, you can always find a cycle that is more negative by just traversing the cycle multiple times.

Comment: If so, I think it's NP-hard, by reduction from the longest-path problem; see https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/83673/755.

Comment: I am looking for the most negative cycle where no edges repeat.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify that in the question, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!

Comment: I suggest trying to prove it is NP-hard by reduction from the longest-path problem, by constructing the dual graph (replace each edge with a vertex and each vertex with an edge).  Does that lead to a working reduction?